# How do I find the largest number from a list and its occurrences using lambdas?

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Please find below a code that counts the number of occurrences of numbers in  a stream and returns a map with the number as the key and the value as its occurrences across the stream:

```
Map<Integer, Long> collect = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 55555, 12)
                .collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), counting()));
```

How do I limit the resulting map to only the biggest number (or numbers in case of a tie)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this simple example:

```
public static void getMeNumbersWithHighestFrequence3(int[] numbers, int howMany) {

    Map<Integer, Long> collect = IntStream.of(numbers).boxed().collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), TreeMap::new, counting())).descendingMap().entrySet().stream()
            .limit(howMany)
            .collect(TreeMap::new, (map, entry) -> map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()), Map::putAll);

}
```

You could also somehow search for them by putting a filter value and it will take all entries with key values greater than that value, something like:

```
  public static void getMeNumbersWithHighestFrequenceByFilterNumber(int[] numbers, int value) {

        Map<Integer, Long> collect = IntStream.of(numbers).boxed().collect(groupingBy(Function.identity(), TreeMap::new, counting())).descendingMap().headMap(value, true);

    }
```

---

> Simple usage:

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 55555, 12};
        getMeNumbersWithHighestFrequence(numbers, 5);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get the most frequent numbers in your stream. Therefore you can use a [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) collecting all the results and getting the list of the last entry:

```
Map<Integer, Long> collect = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 55555, 12)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, TreeMap::new, Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)))
        .lastEntry().getValue();
```

This returns a list of entries containing the number and the frequency. In your case it prints:

```
{4=2}
```

In case you just want to get the number of occurrences of the biggest number you can use this:

```
Map.Entry<Integer, Long> collect = Stream.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 55555, 12)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .max(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        .orElse(null);
```

Which prints:

```
55555=1
```

In the last case you only have one (the max value) return entry. You can also use a `TreeMap` the get the max value, should have a better performance.

Answer (score 0):

I hope someone can come up with a simpler solution:

```
 List<Entry<Integer, Long>> list =
        List.of(3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1)
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Map<Integer, Long> result = new HashMap<>();
    Iterator<Entry<Integer, Long>> iter = list.iterator();
    Entry<Integer, Long> left;
    Entry<Integer, Long> right = null;
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        left = iter.next();
        if (right == null) {
            result.put(left.getKey(), left.getValue());
        }
        if (iter.hasNext() && (right = iter.next()).getValue().longValue() == left.getValue()) {
            result.put(right.getKey(), right.getValue());
        } else {
             break;
        }
    }
```

So first collect them to the same map that you already have. Then sort them by the value; then iterate that result and get *only* those that are at the very beginning and match their values.

The idea is that since these are already sorted by value: `3 = 2; 4 = 2; 5 = 2; 1 = 1` - we only need to iterate as long as that `2` is repeated, as soon as there is no such match, we are done (because they are sorted and thus any element that follows and `!= 2` is only going to be smaller).

Comment: Isn't my solution a bit simpler?

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp did you try it with the sample I have here?

Comment: My solution returns `[3=2, 4=2, 5=2]`. Is that not correct?

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp it does, I miss-read your answer, but do not forget that `OP` was a `Map` as a result

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `MoreCollectors` defined in [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) or my library [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common):

```
int result = Stream.of(1, 2, 12, 3, 4, 4, 55555, 12)
    .collect(MoreCollectors.maxAll(MoreCollectors.countingInt()));

// map result
Map<Integer, Integer> mapResult = Stream.of(1, 2, 12, 3, 4, 4, 55555, 12)
    .collect(maxAll(groupingBy(Function.identity(), countingInt())));
```

Because you may want to: 1) sum of all the largest numbers, or 2) map them to something else, or 3)...More.
Don't need and should not write this kind of specific codes only for one specific user case. (if you want to know how to implement it, just download the source code of the libraries or decompile the class. They're published at Apache License v2)

**Update**. Actually I think probably it's wrong question to ask if you're talking about numbers because the traditional `for-loop` is much more simple and efficient than using lambdas:

```
int[] nums = {1, 2, 12, 3, 4, 4, 55555, 12, 55555};
int[] result = {Integer.MIN_VALUE, 0}; // [0] is the largest number if [1] (occurrence) is bigger than 0.

for (int num : nums) {
  if (num > result[0]) {
    result[0] = num;
    result[1] = 1;
  } else if (num == result[0]) {
    result[1]++;
  }
}

System.out.println(result[0] + ": " + result[1]);
```

if you have to go with Stream/Lambdas:

```
int[] result = IntStream.of(nums).collect(() -> new int[] {Integer.MIN_VALUE, 0}, (a, num) -> {
  if (num > a[0]) {
    a[0] = num;
    a[1] = 1;
  } else if (num == a[0]) {
    a[1]++;
  }
}, (a1, a2) -> {
  if (a1[0] == a2[0]) {
    a1[1] += a2[1];
  } else if (a1[0] < a2[0]) {
    a1[1] = a2[1];
  }
});

System.out.println(result[0] + ": " + result[1]);
```